# Combine Duplicate Values in SQLite Read-Only View

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates

Using a baby names database in SQLite, "Write a query that shows the number of babies born in each region. Exclude the blank region. Modify the query to deal with the duplicate region as if you only have read-only access to the database."

The below query addresses everything but the duplicate region (see screenshot). Some lines have "New England" instead of "New_England" and I need to know how to group these without modifying the database:

```
SELECT r.region, SUM(n.frequency) as BABIES FROM names n
LEFT JOIN regions r on n.state = r.state
WHERE r.region IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY region
ORDER BY BABIES DESC;
```

Query results with duplicate region boxed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

````
select region_clean, sum(frequency) as num_babies 
from (select case when r.region='New England' then 'New_England' else r.region end as region_clean, n.frequency
  from names n
  left join regions r
  ON n.state = r.state) as regions_names
where region_clean IS NOT NULL
group by region_clean;```
````